# Database synchronization time in cassandra

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, distributed-database

I have two controllers accessing distributed database. I am receiving some data from a device to the controllers and i store them in Cassandra database. I use Docker to install cassandra

The node 1 is on controller 1 and node 2 is on controller 2. I would like to know if there is a possibility to measure the time it takes to update the node 2, when i receive data at node 1.

I would like to draw a graph with it. So could someone tell me how do i measure it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra provides tools and insights of all this internal information with the [nodetool gossipinfo](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/gossipinfo.html) command and [cqlsh tracing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html).

In the scenario that you are proposing, I'm inferring that you are using a Replication Factor of 2, and that you are interested in the exact time that is taking to have the information written in all the nodes, you can measure the time required to do a write with  [the consistency level set to ALL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html), and compare it with similar writes using the consistency level of ONE. The difference of the times will be the propagation from one node to the other.

Finally, if you are interested in measuring the performance of the queries in Cassandra, there are several tools that enhance the tracing functionality, in our team we have been using [zipkin](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2015/12/07/using-zipkin-for-full-stack-tracing-including-cassandra.html) with good results.

Comment: Monroy Thanks, The tracing option is available in docker? Because i used docker to install cassandra

Comment: it should be available with docker, as that is a feature of the Cassandra engine